# How to redirect 301 staging subdomain urls with subfolder to root with subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I am sorry if this question may have been asked before but I would like to know if there is automatic code or lines of code to handle the 301 redirects for the subdomain with subfolder to root with subdomain as following:

Example:

Old url: https://staging.domain.com.au/subfolder

To

New url: https://www.domain.com.au/subfolder

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please note that the subdomain was created in Wordpress and there was no subdomain folder nor subfolder directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this redirect rule in site root `.htaccess` **above all other rules**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.domain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subfolder/ https://www.domain.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,NC]

# remaining rules go here
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, but the site was created in wordperss, meaning no actual directory exist for both subdomain and subdirectory. how do we go with this?